# process values of records

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, rdd

I am new to Spark and I couldn't find enough information to understand some things in Spark. I am trying to write a pseudocode in scala (like these examples http://spark.apache.org/examples.html)

A file with data is given. Each line has some data: number, course name, credits, and mark.

```
123 Programming_1 10 75
123 History       5  80
```

I am trying to compute the average of each student (number). Average is the sum of every course credits*Mark a student had took
divided by the sum of every course credits the student took. Ignoring any line that has mark==NULL. Suppose that I have a function parseData(line) which makes a line with strings to record with 4 member : number, coursename, credits,  mark.

What I tried until now

```
data=spark.textFile(“hdfs://…”)
line=data.filter(mark=> mark != null)
line= line.map(line => parseData(line))
data = parallelize(List(line))  
groupkey= data.groupByKey()  
               ((a,b,c)=>(a, sum(mul(b,c))/ sum(b))
```

But I don't know how to read the specific values and use them to produce the average for each student. Is it possible to use array?

Answer (score 0):

Once you filter and get the dataframe, you could use something like this:

```
df.withColumn("product",col("credits")*col("marks"))
.groupBy(col("student"))
.agg(sum("credits").as("sumCredits"),sum("product").as("sumProduct"))
.withColumn("average",col("sumProduct")/col("sumCredits"))
```

Hope this helps!!

Comment: I don't understand. What language is it? can you do it like these examples here? https://spark.apache.org/examples.html

Comment: It is in written in scala

Comment: There are two levels of abstraction in spark - RDD(low level api) and Dataframes and  datasets (high level api). The above code is for dataframe approach

Comment: I see. Is this code complete as for the data members and Ignoring any line that has mark==NULL? What df.withColumn, and agg does?

Comment: Nope - this does not filter nulls, you could use df.filter / df.where to filter out nulls. Do this operation before getting product of credits and marks.

Comment: withColumn - adds a new column to the dataframe, first parameter is the name of the column and the second parameter is the value it takes

Comment: agg function works on grouped dataframe, it will aggregate your grouped data using the function specified in it and return one value for one group